# Is there research on how successfully chess can discipline children?

Tags: teaching, children, studies-published-report

According to the article [Armenia makes chess compulsory in schools](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/nov/15/armenia-chess-compulsory-schools), Armenia made chess mandatory in school for the sake of discipline. A lot of people in the real world don't work together to organize plans properly and really suffer the consequences later so I suspect Armenia figured that kids need to get disciplined in order to grow up as a person who works harder to organize plans. Maybe the Carnegie foundation did some research on it.

As an extra note, I found out about the Carnegie foundation from the question [What does math education research know about difficulty vs. effectiveness?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/875/what-does-math-education-research-know-about-difficulty-vs-effectiveness) Maybe some day, there will be some Stack Exchange users who will be very willing and able to adopt an advanced research technique with one another. Then through that technique, they might eventually eventually find a connection between this question and the question [What does math education research know about difficulty vs. effectiveness?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/875/what-does-math-education-research-know-about-difficulty-vs-effectiveness) through my reference to it in this question and then help direct Stack Exchange users to many very similar questions.

Comment: The question is very narrow. If you want papers on JUST "how successfully chess can discipline children", I did not find any. I did find a lot that includes that as that is part of virtually any study, but even there, if you are looking for a specific number, in other words, to quantify it, what I found did not include that. They mention in it passing as one of the benefits.

Comment: I wonder if this question is more suitable for Academia Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot, but [it's probably hogowash](https://journals.plos.org/plosmedicine/article?id=10.1371/journal.pmed.0020124)